# Android: force scan getContentResolver() when new files added

Tags: android, android-sqlite

When my application is started i call this method :

```
private String scanDeviceForMp3() {
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
Cursor cursor = null;
List<Mp3DataModel> mp3DataList = new ArrayList<>();
String jsonMp3List = "";

String[] projection = {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE,
        MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
};
final String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED + " COLLATE LOCALIZED DESC";

try {
    Log.e("TAG", "------------>");
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {...
```

And i get list of mp3 files.

Now i added new mp3s by connecting mobile to pc and  copies some mp3 files into external storage but when i run app and call `scanDeviceForMp3()' new mp3 files not detected till i restart mobile?

How can i force scan like `activity.getContentResolver().query` to get all music again?

Comment: "new mp3 files not detected till i restart mobile" -- they will not be available in `MediaStore` until `MediaStore` indexes them. If the media was copied outside of your app, you have no good means on modern Android versions to force `MediaStore` to update its index.

Comment: Ok, What is your suggestion? Tell to user to restart phone? or is a way to notify MediaStore to index medias?@CommonsWare

Comment: "or is a way to notify MediaStore to index medias?" -- as I noted, I am not aware of a way to do that on modern versions of Android. That is supposed to be handled by the OS itself, but device manufacturer changes might interfere with it.

Comment: It is possible after a wile, MediaStore do  index medias? @CommonsWare

Comment: The `MediaStore` will index those files eventually. How long "eventually" will take probably varies by device. Early Android devices would check every 6 hours. In my recent experience, indexing seems much more rapid -- when I copy stuff over to a Google Pixel device, `MediaStore` seems to be updated in less than a minute.

Comment: If i download mp3 files  into external storage for example into Download folder by app , does MediaStore index them immediately@CommonsWare?

Comment: If *your* app is doing the downloads, then you know about them and can help the `MediaStore`. On Android 9 and earlier, you can use `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` for that. On Android 10 and higher, you can use `insert()` on `MediaStore` to get a `Uri` that you can use to update `MediaStore` *and* for storing the content. I demonstrate that in [this sample Kotlin app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos), where I download videos and get them indexed by the `MediaStore`.